# NPM script containing parentheses syntax error

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have the following NPM script in my package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)"
  }
}
```

And after I run `npm run lint` I get the following error:

```
> tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)'
```

It seems that I cannot use the character **(** in my NPM script. How can I come around this? The script is a valid bash script.

I tried searching the issue but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind thanks!

**Update:**

It seems that running this command in my terminal (macOS) like so:

```
bash -c "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)"
```

I get the exact same error.

however if I run it like this:

```
bash -c "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?\(.test\).ts?\(x\)"
```

it seems to work in the terminal. But not in a NPM script.

**Got it to work like so:**

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "lint": "bash -c \"tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)'\"",
   }
}
```

or the more simpler version

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)'",
    }
}
```

Credits go to @shellter.

Comment: Maybe try to escape it like so: `tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?\(.test\).ts?\(x\)`

Comment: tried it... still getting the error. I also tried with bash -c "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/**?\(.test\).ts?\(x\)" with and without escaping.

Comment: how about `bash -c "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/**?(.test).ts?(x)' "` ? (note the single-quote surrounding the problematic pattern (you may want/need to remove the space between `'` and `"` that I included for visibility) ). Good luck.

Comment: yes, thanks @shellter, that was it!. I posted an update with the final fix.

Comment: I couldnt get my bash scripts to work with npm, using the `bash -c` prefix helped. Is it because `npm run` is using node runtime?

Comment: I think it is an "issue" on how node execs the commands and passes in the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote this script to make a basic syntax check on my javascript files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -x "$(command -v parallel)" ]; then
    find src/js -name "*.js" | parallel --no-notice --jobs 4 --gnu nodejs -c
else
    find src/js -name "*.js" | xargs -L1 -d '\n' nodejs -c
fi
```

This will lint every javascript file within src/js and utilize parallel if available. If you have a cpu with more threads, you might want to increase the jobs parameter to match your threads-count.

I hope this is of some help to you